# Print contents of list based on element's x,y position (discrete whole numbers)

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, list, printing

I have a generic list of "cubes". Each cube has a position (x,y). There are no cubes in the list with the same position. The position of each cube's x and y is an integer, only discrete whole numbers. Finally the list is not sorted.

I want to print the list based on the position of the cubes. How would I go about doing this?

Since the positions are whole numbers, I was thinking of using a 2d array. Find the minimum y value in the list. Once I have the min y value and if it is negative, I can add the absolute value of the min y to every cubes y value (no more negative y values). I could do this for the x values as well. From here I just add the contents to the 2d array and printing it is simple.

I tend to over think things? Is there a simpler way, more efficient way?

I am using C#.

Comment: `based on the position of the cubes` ? As in, closer to Origin (0,0) comes first, and so on ?

Comment: As if it were a cartesian plane and I am plotting the elements on the graph. I want to repressent this on stdout .

Answer (score 1):

I am not writing code but can tell you an approach:

> 1. Find the distance of each point from a reference point (say 0,0).
> 2. Save the index of points in another array based on their distance calculated (ascending).
> 3. When all the distances are found, print the points based on the sorting done on basis of distance.